# Make adsense ad of type Image, 728x90 responsive

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, osclass

I've placed two ads in a  side by side
each ad is of dimensions 200x90 (adlinks) and 728x90(Image Ad)
My website is responsive using bender theme of osclass.
when I visit the page in mobile  the 728x90 image is occupying still 728 px of width.

I've tried to keep it in a div and added `class="hide-mobile hide-tablet"` but this tip is not working.

Any suggestions?

I don't want to display this 728x90 ad when the screen becomes responsive.

Answer (score 1):

As it is written in Google Adsense Guidelines (https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3213689?hl=en), you just need to select **“Responsive ad unit (BETA)”** from the Ad size drop-down menu before generating your code.

Answer (score 1):

Use media queries `@media`.
That'll surely do it.
Read up about media queries [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

This is a git repository for your exact purpose: https://github.com/bassjobsen/bootstrap-responsive-ads

Here is how your function should look like:

```
mediaCheck({
    media: '(max-width: 720px)',
    entry: function() {

       "hide-my-ad-or-something"

      }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use that:
[responsive image in bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-responsive-images)
but if you have image and you want do this responsive you can:
1) add clas to his img
and set this style:

```
display:block;
width: 200px;
height: auto;
```

use media queries and change width if you need smaller or larger images.